# nextjs _middleware not console.log

Tags: next.js, nodes, middleware

I have followed the guideline to insert a middleware into one of my pages.

in the sub directory /appstore I have created `_middleware.js` inside that I am trying to just get something to console log so I know the file is working.

The end result will be that I want to detect if they are android or iOS and redirect them to the correct store.

```
import { NextFetchEvent, NextRequest } from 'next/server'

export function middleware() {
  console.log('Hello, world!')
}
```

However when I visit the page I get in console.log = NULL so clearly something is not quite right?

Comment: Where are you looking for the `console.log`? The output should appear in the terminal where you started the Next.js dev server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the middleware works **server side** you can see the `console.log()` results only **on the terminal** where you execute the `npm run dev` or `npm run start` command.

It will display nothing on the client (browser console).

Just for reference, adding the Documentation for the [next/server](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/server) server-only helpers.